# Cannot run unit tests for an application developed with Compact Framework for Windows CE 6.0 platform

Tags: compact-framework, device-emulation, smart-device

I'm developing a solution for Windows CE 6.0 using GuD_AtomKit X86 Device emulator. 
I'm not able to run any unit tests, because I get following error message:

The test adapter ('Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') required to execute this test could not be loaded. Check that the test adapter is installed properly. Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.TestHostAdapter.DeviceAgent.TestAlreadyRunningException' was thrown.

But there's no unit test running on the device.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was probably caused by a hardware issue. After I updated the flash with the board I was running the test against, it started to work again. So probably a bug in the firmware of the board... :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the target device in your testrunconfig file?  Running against the target device is definitely supported.

You also might have to manually deploy the CF to the device as the Unit Test framework doesn't auto-deploy it.

Comment: yes, I changed the target device appropriately. And I also double checked if the deployment works OK. Unfortunately, it did not help.